# Json and php: How can I parse this array (object)

Tags: php, json

I have this JSON response:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
  ["data"]=>
  array(47) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#2 (4) {
      ["id"]=>
      int(341)
      ["competition_id"]=>
      int(1)
      ["name"]=>
      string(9) "2015/2016"
      ["active"]=>
      bool(true)
```

But I don't know how to parse the data.

I tried it with this PHP code:

```
echo $json->data[0]->id;
```

But it doesn't work. How can I get the ID for example?

Comment: your response is *not* JSON...

Comment: sorry this was the output of the json_decode() method...

Comment: Then `echo $json->data[0]->id;` should work.

Comment: Or do you want data from all the `$json->data` array properties

Comment: at the same moment i found it out :p THANKS!

Answer (score -1):

here is my solution:

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);

$json2 = json_decode($json);

echo $json2->data[0]->id;
```

sorry for complication, the goal was the json_decode() function, after that I can get the data with "->"

greetings!